# How to take list as an input in command line option format in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to take a list from the user, using command line options for the input.
The perl script is shown below. Here Input 3 must be a list provided from shell. I don't know what should I put in there for a list, hence used a string.

```
my %Inputs =(
  "Company_name=s"        =>\my $Input1,
  "Place=s"               =>\my $Input2,
  "Revenue=s"             =>\my @Input3,
  "No_of_Employee=i"      =>\my $Input4,
);

These Inputs are then used inside a subroutine

subroute ($Input1, $Input2, @Input3, $Input4);
```

The command line format for input is

```
./my.pl -Input1 user/file1 -Input2 user/file2 -Input3 ...
```

I don't know how and what format I should enter the list in command line. And also while taking list as input what should i specify it as string (s) or what for a list.

Comment: Which module are you using for getting the inputs? Is this one of the Getopt family? Please [edit] your question and show us more of your code.

Comment: If you're using `Getopt::Long`, then this is how you should execute the script. `perl my.pl -Input1 <input1_value> -Input2 <input1_value> -Input3 <input3_value1> -Input3 <input3_value2> -Input3 <input3_value3>`. For more info [see](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Long#Options-with-multiple-values) this.

Comment: Hi vkk05, no i am not using getopt. This code is like the way, i have presented. The inputs are taken this way and then processed further in the code.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::). The [docs about repeating arguments](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#Options-with-multiple-values) give multiple ways of doing this.

The way you've written your code lets you repeat the same argument multiple times.

```perl
GetOptions( "foo=s" => \my @foo);
print Dumper \@foo;

# $ ./bar.pl --foo hello --foo world
# [ "foo", "bar" ]
```

Alternatively you can make it take multiple values on the same option.

```perl
GetOptions( "foo={,}" => \my @foo);
print Dumper \@foo;

# $./bar.pl --foo hello world "how are you?"
# [ "foo", "bar", "how are you?" ]
```

The `{,}` means it needs zero or more inputs, making it optional. It's similar to regex quantifiers. You can also do:

- `{2}` - exactly two
- `{2,}` - two or more
- `{2,4}` - between two or four

Comment: Thanks for replying simbaque.
This is just a representation, actual code has some real names of variables and not Input1, Input2 etc.
Also, i haven't used getoptions(), the issue is this code is written by someone else, and i am stuck to enter a list using this.

Comment: @PrakharShukla if you're using something else, you need to show us what. We don't know what your code is like. You haven't shown us actual processing of `@ARGV`, and your code looks like it's using a module from the Getopt:: family. Please show us more context, and we'll try to help.